# Vendor branch in TFS

Tags: svn, tfs, branch, vendor

In Subversion there is a pattern called [Vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html) to keep track of changes made by my self in a third party project. I´am not really sure how to do this in TFS, are there any best practicies? Is this procedure called anything else in TFS? I cant find anything like this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In svn, vendor branches are just a convention, like the trunk/tags/branches top folders are just convention. You can implement the same convention in TFS.

If you are a third party contributor to a project, and have TFS access, your own branch does make sense. One advantage of this pattern is that the owner of this project can give you control over your vendor folder, and you can have your own set of sub branches, which you can merge into each other, or the project owner can merge into his trunk or version branches.